# In React Is there a way to change the background color of a parent Label tag on a Radio Input checked?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am using React Semantic UI. In css I am trying to change the Background color of a Parent label of an input, so when the radio button is clicked it changes colors. I am hiding the radio button with display none. Since the label gives it a nice button look. Here is my code. In html I just used a input tag and changed the span but it has to be done differently with the react semantic ui library. I was able to get it to work with input and span like in my html version but in this case the click functionality wouldn't work.

Here is a CodeSandbox with the React Semantic Ui Library loaded in its implements the first answer but does not work. https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-tereshkova-u9toz?fontsize=14

I Added the "Compiled" html

```
<Segment>
    <Menu attached="top" borderless={true}>
        <Menu.Item>
            <Header>
                 Scale:
            </Header>
            <Label className="filter_check" size="large">
                 <Form.Field
                     label="Year"
                     control='input'
                     type='radio'
                     name='year'
                 />
            </Label>
        </Menu.Item>
    </Menu>
</Segment>
```

```
.filter_check input {
    display: none;
}
input:checked + .filter_check>.label {
    background: #00b5ad !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}

.field input[type=radio]:checked + label {
    background: red;
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 1em;
    padding: .3em .78571429em;
}
```

"complied"  html

```
<div class="ui segment">
   <div class="ui borderless top attached menu">
      <div class="item">
         <div class="ui header">Scale:</div>
         <div class="ui large label filter_check">
            <div class="field"><label><input name="year" type="radio"> Year</label></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the "compiled" HTML of your React code?

Comment: Added it do you need the order of the scripts?

Comment: I'm afraid you just have a typo: `.label` instead of `label`. And the `!important` will not allow the override to take place

Comment: Ive tried both because of the ```<div class="ui large label filter_check">```

Comment: Oh then the `+` should be a `~`, as the `label` **precedes** the `input`

Comment: didn't work could you share a working version with code sandbox

Comment: Or at least a corrected version here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After viewing the SandBox, I was able to see that the React code compiles to the following HTML:

```html
<div class="ui large label filter_check">
  <div class="field">
  <label>
  <input name="year" type="radio"> Year
  </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then I figured you want to modify the **parent** element upon clicking the `input` field. This is not trivial and required modifying the parent element, which I did using the `onChange` prop of the `<Form.Field>`:

```
<Label className="filter_check" size="large">
    <Form.Field
        label="Year"
        control="input"
        type="radio"
        name="year"
        onChange={checkInput}
    />
</Label>
```

With the following function, that adds the `checked` class to the modified element:

```
function checkInput(e) {
    let labelElement = e.target.parentNode;
    let bgElement = labelElement.parentNode.parentNode;
    bgElement.classList.add('checked');
}
```

Then we update the CSS with the following:

```
div.ui.large.label.filter_check.checked {
    background-color: red;
}
```

And - [Voilà](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-label-background-color-notchanging-fnhfj?fontsize=14)!